# Annoying TableView while using Twitter API

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, twitter

Hello I am making an application using twitter api. I have a tablevViewController, that loads followers and people we follow (friends). Then, this tableViewController checks if friends are our followers. If user as user in the friends array doesn't follow us, it will be sent to 'results' array and tableview loads that data.But when I scroll the tableview, some annoying things happens. Here is my code and video link;
[Click to go to video.](https://youtu.be/K7NRpuXmI6A)

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
var results = NSMutableArray()
var following = NSArray()
var followers = NSArray()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.reloadData()
    Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("GET", URL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json", parameters: ["user_id":Twitter.sharedInstance().session().userID], error: nil), completion: {(response:NSURLResponse?, data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        var dic = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
        var friends = dic["ids"] as! NSArray
        self.following = friends
        Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("GET", URL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json", parameters: ["user_id":Twitter.sharedInstance().session().userID], error: nil), completion: {(resonse:NSURLResponse?,data:NSData?,error:NSError?) -> Void in
            var dic = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
            var followers = dic["ids"] as! NSArray
            self.followers = followers
            for id in self.following {
                if !self.followers.containsObject(id) {
                    var st = id as! NSNumber
                    Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.loadUserWithID(st.stringValue, completion: {(user:TWTRUser?,error:NSError?) -> Void in
                        self.results.addObject(user!)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        println("done")
                    })
                }
            }

        })
    })} override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellid", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "You have \(results.count) bad friends."
        return cell
    }else {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellid", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        var user = results.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row-1) as! TWTRUser
        cell.user = user
        cell.label.text = user.name
        cell.imageFrame.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: user.profileImageLargeURL)!)!)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: When yo reuse cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to reset the cell state. At the moment you don't clear the user/image etc in the if or the text label in the else.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you give me an example code?

Answer (score 0):

As your table view scrolls, cells will be re-used - the object returned from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` may be a new cell or it may be an object that has been used previously - in this case the old content will still be there.

If you have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass then you can implement the `prepareForReuse` method in that class to clear the old content or you need to set things up in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` -

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellid", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "You have \(results.count) bad friends."
        cell.user = nil
        cell.label.text=""
        cell.imageFrame.image=nil 
        return cell
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text=""
        cell.user = user
        cell.label.text = user.name
        cell.imageFrame.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: user.profileImageLargeURL)!)!)
        return cell
    }
    return cell
}
```